# what is exposed ground meaning in passive antenna layout?

Tags: antenna, ground, layout

Could someone help me understand what is the meaning of exposed ground in pcb layout. I'm designing layout of my project and one of the component on it is passive antenna. What does exposed ground meaning?

[image]

Comment: Usually this would mean a pad (looks like 18mm square in your case) connected to the ground plane without soldermask. It would help to read the datasheet of your device though, please provide that.

Comment: If this is a GNSS antenna, in addition of soldermask, solderpaste should be defined. Check with your assembly house if they prefer a ground pattern rather than a giant ground slab, or sometimes they'll do this themselves.